# Twitter Bootstrap3 - Make An Accordion Expand On A Different Page When A Link Is Clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I raised a question before about how to expand an accordion on a link click:

[Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Auto Expand An Accordion When A Link Clicked In Another Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176641/twitter-bootstrap-3-auto-expand-an-accordion-when-a-link-clicked-in-another-ac)

To which I got the solution for, but now I have a different issue, how do I expand an accordion on another page from clicking a link on another page.

I have tried various ways as shown below none seem to work:

```
 1. <a class="collapsed" href="[PATH NAME]/#" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#collapseTwo">Test</a>
 2. <a class="collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="[PATH NAME]/#collapseTwo">Test</a>
 3. <a class="collapsed" href="[PATH NAME]" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="[PATH NAME]/#collapseTwo">Test</a>
```

Comment: None of those will work because the collapse is on another page, you need a script for that. See answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer here answers your question:

[Bootstrap Collapse - open the given id fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412778/bootstrap-collapse-open-the-given-id-fragment)

Put EITHER in your jQuery or JS

```
// === opens a collapse from a url
location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
```

OR -- not both

```
// === opens a collapse from a url
var anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
$(".collapse").collapse('hide'); // REMOVE THIS it and it will work more smoothly
$("#" + anchor).collapse('show');
```

The latter requires a load function. `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Then link to the collapsed section with the UNIQUE id like you would normally link to an anchor:

```
<a href="thepage.html#uniqueID">Link text</a>
```

Comment: this time you're helping someone else i helped before (i answered their question they referred in this one)... upvoted it ;) haia!

Comment: @Christina went with the first option and works great. Thanks